# How to replace NaN values in the weights of neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, initialization, nan

I am trying to replace NaN values in the weights with some constant. However I am unaware on how one can do so.

I am aware that to access weights, I have to write.

```
for i in model.params:
    arr = i.clone()
    arr[torch.isnan(arr)] = 0
    param_list.append(nn.Parameter(arr))
    
model.params= param_list
```

But this breaks the computation graph, any better way you can suggest me for the same?

Comment: how does your `model` definition look like? `clone` doesn't affect the computation graph (i.e., it's a reference). So you can simply update the `NaN`s with 0 values by iterating over the `model.parameters()`, thereby the use of `param_list` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```py
with torch.no_grad():
  for p in model.parameters():
    p.data[torch.isnan(p.data)] = 0
```